# IIS Mirrored Servers - Shared Configuration Alternative

Tags: iis

I have been using the IIS Shared Configuration feature for several years to manage mirrored web servers.  Today, I experienced networking issues, Hyper-V related, where the primary web server that hosts the shared config was unavailable.  This resulted in the secondary web server not able to read the shared applicationHost.config.

I found this article that provides a solution using DFS
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-hosting/configuring-servers-in-the-windows-web-platform/offline-files-for-shared-configuration

Should I just eliminate the IIS Shared Configuration option and just use DFS to synchronize a local copy of the configs for each server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using DFS to synchronize configuration files you can consider the following:

1. Each server has its own copy of the configuration, so if one server becomes unavailable, the others can continue to operate, reducing the risk of a single point of failure.
2. With DFS, you need to manage the synchronization process manually. This can be time-consuming, especially if changes are frequent.
3. DFS setup and management can be more complex than relying on the built-in IIS share configuration.
4. If multiple administrators use DFS to manage different servers, there may be conflicts when synchronizing changes.

If high availability and reducing single points of failure are critical, and you're willing to manually manage synchronization, then DFS might be a good choice.